# Book on differential geometry which uses germs

Tags: differential-geometry, book-recommendation, germs

I would like to start learning differential geometry and I find the concept of [germs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)) very beautiful and enlightening. Unfortunately, I have [Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387217529), which only mentions them without using them.
Is there any differential geometry book which develops the theory around germs, and adapted for a first course in differential geometry? If so, is it a good idea to start learning with that point of view? Or would you rather advise me to learn the classical approach first?

Comment: As much as my younger self would have loved the extra abstraction, with the benefit of bitter experience, I'd advise you as strongly as possible to drink as deeply as possible of the concrete examples: curves, (hyper)surfaces, projective spaces, matrix Lie groups, homogeneous spaces of matrix Lie groups. Even if you skip a dedicated course on classical differential geometry of curves and surfaces and go straight to general differentiable manifolds, make sure that you get as much hands-on computational experience as possible with the major classes of concrete examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Global calculus" by Ramanan is a good book to have a look at. Though I would not consider it an introduction to smooth manifolds and would be more profitably read by someone that already has the hands-on experience that Branimir mentions.